# How to make the element inside the div no obstruct by the static footer?

Tags: html, css

In this case,I had created a static footer and the element inside the div like button(which alway at the bottom),I had managed to make the height of the div bigger but found that is no efficient to used while the element inside the div was increased and expended.Is it some suggestion else to make it dynamically?thanks.

The sample output might look like this:

[image]

Comment: You can add `padding-bottom` to your content container div.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you say static, do you mean a fixed position at the bottom of the window? If so then whatever your height, e.g. 20px, make that the value of the bottom-padding for the main area, then anything in the main area will be padded equally by the height of the footer and will be seen.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [working model](http://jsfiddle.net/eAgau/1/) for you on JSFiddle.

In **HTML**, there are 2 divs, "wrapper" and "footer", like:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    line 1 <br />
</div>
<div id="footer">
    footer text
</div>
```

In **CSS**:

```
html, body {
    height: 95%;
}

#wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: -1.5em;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
}

#footer {
    position: absolute; !important
    bottom: 0;
}
```